# Load HTML page in a service with its own CSS Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Service, `PrintService` that I have added to my application. The Service extracts elements from a page and renders another window with the contents of the extracted elements.

```typescript
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrintService {
  popupPrint(selector: string) {
    const printContents = (document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLTableElement).innerHTML;
    const popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
    popupWin?.document.open();
    popupWin?.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
            .d-flex  {
              width: 100%;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
            }
            
             // ... More CSS

            @media print {
              .d-print-none {
                display: none;
              }
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <section class='d-print-none'>
            <button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
            <button onclick="window.close();">Cancel</button>
          </section>
            ${printContents}
        </body>
        <script>
        (function() {
           window.print();
        })();
        </script>
      </html>`
    );
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

This works. [Print Service on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xfcp6q)

My Problem now is this, I need to be remove the css styles from the service above to its own file, How can I be able to achieve this

My initial plan was to move it to a text file and read the text file from angular but I believe there is a better approach

### Edit 1

**Why do I need to have this on a separate style sheet?**

I am building an application on a dark theme using `bootstrap` css. I need to extract the table and print it on a light theme. I think users would prefer to print a black text on white background.

I have a `PrintComponent`

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-print',
  templateUrl: './print.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print.component.less']
})
export class PrintComponent {

  @Input() selector: string;

  constructor(private printService: PrintService) {
  }

  print(): void {
    this.printService.popupPrint(this.selector);
  }
```

And Html is just a button

```html
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)='print()' type="button">
  Print <span class="icon-print"></span>
</button>
```

The Idea is to a simple way to print any item on a page e.g I can have

```html
<app-print selector='#reportTable'>
<table id='reportTable'>
  <!-- Contents of this table will be extracted and displayed for printing -->
</table>
```

**What would I consider a better approach?**

- Currently, my `PrintService` is a large file. Extracting it to a different file will at least solve this problem.
- Next If the file can be added to the minification process, that would be great
- I also hope of a way to 'lazy load' this service only when required
- If possible, can I simply have a link to this stylesheet? something like `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="some/print/style.css"></link>`

Comment: Why not use `ng-template` to define the layout and styling and use slots for entering the data as needed? There are plenty of good references on how to use templates so you can look into that.

Comment: There are many different ways to move the styles to a separate file here, ranging from outrageous to completely reasonable. I thus encourage you to add more information to the question, namely: what exact problem are you trying to solve and why do you want to extract the CSS? Is it purely to have a separate file, which could, say, use syntax highlighting, or are there other reasons? Also, how do you determine a "better" approach? Is it okay if the new window loads the styles asynchronously? Are you looking for a native Angular approach? Are you looking for some Webpack solution? Etc. Cheers!

Comment: @AbrarHossain, I have been thinking of you suggestion but I seem not be coming up with any plan on how to achieve this using `ng-template` any link to reference would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to cover all of your expectations and even a bit more.

Important: some things might have to be done slightly differently, depending on your Angular/TypeScript configuration. This is for Angular 10 with SCSS.

### 1. Create a separate HTML file for the print window

Create it at e.g. `app/print/print-page.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print tab</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/print-styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="d-print-none">
            <button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
            <button onclick="window.close();">Cancel</button>
        </section>
        {{printContents}}
    </body>
    <script>
        (function () {
            window.print();
        })();
    </script>
</html>
```

Notice that:

- we are loading `/print-styles.css` in the `<head>` - we will create this file and instruct Angular to properly bundle it later;
- there's a token `{{printContents}}`, which we will use to inject custom HTML into the page.

### 2. Add TypeScript typings for HTML files

We will want to import this HTML file into our `print.service.ts` file. To be able to do this, TypeScript needs to understand what kind of data `.html` files hold. This is done via a typing file (`.d.ts`). Create a file `html.d.ts` with this content:

```
declare module '*.html' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

By default, TypeScript will be able to find type declarations anywhere in your source, so place this file wherever you feel like in your source code directory, e.g. `app/print/html.d.ts`.

### 3. Use `raw-loader` to import HTML files

By default an Angular application knows how to import various script/style files. It does not know how to treat HTML files, however. By using a `raw-loader` we will instruct Webpack to import the target file as a simple string without any transformations.

First you need to install the `raw-loader` dependency:

```
npm i -D raw-loader
```

Then you can either:

- configure Angular loaders at the application config level to use `raw-loader` for all files with names ending in `.html` (this can be done using a custom Webpack builder from `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and is out-of-scope for this question);
- use the loader in-place, which is fine for a one-off instance like this and is what we're going to do.

### 4. Create the print service

Now that TypeScript knows how to interpret the HTML file, we can import it into the print service, thus entirely separating the presentation from the service. In `app/print/print.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import printPageHTML from '!!raw-loader!./print-page.html';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PrintService {
  popupPrint(selector: string) {
    const printContents = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
    const popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(printPageHTML.replace('{{printContents}}', printContents));
  }
}
```

Notice here:

- how we import the base HTML for the print window - `import printPageHTML from '!!raw-loader!./print-page.html'`;
- how we inject whatever HTML we want to print using token replace - `printPageHTML.replace('{{printContents}}', printContents)`.

### 5. Write styles for the print window

Create a `app/print/print-styles.scss` file and define your desired styles there. You may import Bootstrap here as well.

```
.d-flex  {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

// ... More CSS

@media print {
  .d-print-none {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

### 6. Bundle the CSS file

We need to instruct Angular to properly bundle `print-styles.scss` so that:

- this CSS is **not** included in the application by default at load time (we want the print window to load it lazily at a later time);
- the file is minified and included in the build with a predictable name (so that we know how to load it - recall step #1).

In `angular.json` (a.k.a. the workspace config) modify the `architect.build.options.styles` path to include the styles file, something like this:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles/styles.scss",
  {
    "input": "src/styles/print-styles.scss",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "print-styles"
  },
  ... other styles here
]
```

Notice `inject` and `bundleName` - both are important.

### The code

I have created a demo repo here: https://github.com/juona/angular-printing-demo. Unfortunately, I was not able to run this on StackBlitz, so better clone the repo and try it on your machine.

### Notes

- Steps 1-3 are optional, but I thought that it would be a good idea to separate the HTML from the service too.
- **If you wish to test this in development mode**, you need to also use the `extractCss` option. This option is enabled by default only for production builds. To turn it on in dev mode, add `"extractCss": true` to `architect.build.options`. If you don't do this, `print-styles.scss` will be bundled into a `print-styles.js` (JavaScript!) file - this is not what we want.
- This is not a very flexible solution because you have to hard-code the name of the CSS file, you must use the `extractCss` flag, using JavaScript is inconvenient as you have to write it inside the `script` tag and so on. But it does seem to achieve exactly what you were looking for.

## Alternative approaches

Here are some alternatives to investigate, just in case, as I'm too lazy to do that myself:

- Angular offers a native solution to open components in separate tabs - I am sure that this could be utilised, especially if more involved print page preparation is required.
- You may also try to use CSS's `all: unset` to unset any styles applied to a component and its children, whilst also hiding any unrelated component while printing is in progress. This would allow you to avoid using new windows/tabs while giving the ability to override global CSS (Bootstrap).

Comment: I am trying to implement this but I seem to be getting problems with the `raw-loader`, `Cannot find module './print-page.html' or its corresponding type declarations.` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k9wsyk

Comment: Alright, so Angular 10 is indeed quite a bit different from v7. I am not a fan of Stackblitz and similar tools when it comes to project configuration, so I have created a Github repo for this and will update the answer to match Angular 10 later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Updated. I made changes all over the answer, so better read it all again. Also, StackBlitz definitely has its limitations : ] not sure if in general or with Angular specifically. E.g. my code does not work whilst your second demo keeps crashing. The devDependencies in your first demo are all over the place and the configuration had issues too, and yet StackBlitz was able to run anyway, which is weird and does not inspire trust. The thing is - just use my repo instead.